# How can I create a QR code for multiple cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a QR code for multiple values in a column. I searched and found that the below formula lets me create a QR Code for a value in cell A1:

```
=IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chl="&A1&"")
```

Trying to expand it into 2 values I tried:

```
=IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chl="&A1&"%0A"&A2&"")
```

But the result of scanning the QR was just a the 2 cells combined. (ex: 404832221400252221)

What I am trying to get is a QR code that will output the entire column of data cell by cell. Something like this:

```
404832221

400252221

...

...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
=INDEX(IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chl="&A1:A))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chl="&
 QUERY(A1:A10;;9^9)))
```

Comment: The QR code produced by this formula still only returns the 1st value in the column. Trying to get 1 QR code for the n numbers in column A. Thank you.

Comment: @USER-RANDOM see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGhHL.png & https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hXb6Y1yZj3qEV-xmsDzNTbKbEt7VUNFWmrXBWL2iFsI/edit#gid=1875701050

Comment: I don't need 1 QR code for each value. I need 1 QR Code that outputs all the values in Column A. So 1 QR that holds the data of multiple cells. EX. Numbers 1-20 in individual cells in Col. A under 1 QR Code that when scanned into sheets will output 1-20 in separate cells in column

Comment: @USER-RANDOM I see. try the updated answer. I have no tools to test this but my guess is that it will output all numbers separated by a space so you will need some script or formula to split those numbers into multiple cells

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to arrange the data in different rows, but the below formula will add space after every data.

```
=HYPERLINK("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="&A1&" "&A2&" "&A3&" "&A4,"QR CODE")
```

Comment: Hi @Utkarsh Agrawal the solution you provided doesn't display the image of the QR CODE instead the output is a link [QR CODE](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=404832221%20400252221%2012345)